# Deep array selection with lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have barely used lodash and I’m trying to use it now for a simple task.

I have a working solution, but it looks complex and I wonder if there’s a easy shorthand to the task using the library utilities.

`items` is an array of objects like the following:

```
{
    id: ‘string’,
    val_1: ‘string’,
    val_2: ‘string’,
    components: array of: {
        val_3: ‘string’,
        val_4: ‘string’,
        types: array of strings
    }
}
```

I want to select an object whose components array holds *valid types*.
Valid types are defined by me in an array of about 10 strings. This is my solution:

```
var validTypes = [‘type1’,’type3’,’type5’];
var desired = _.find(items, (item) => {
    var allowed = true;
    _.forEach(item.components, (component) => {
        // Remove valid types. What's left should be empty.
        _.pullAll(component.types, validTypes);
        allowed = allowed && _.isEmpty(component.types);
    })
    return allowed;
});
```

As said, I wonder how this can be improved, I feel like I’m not using lodash correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `_.pullAll` mutate your objects and should not be used.

You can use instead `_.every` and `_.some`, this will stop the loop once it is found an unacceptable value.

```
var validTypes = [‘type1’,’type3’,’type5’];
var desired = _.find(items, (item) => {
    return _.every(item.components, (component) => { // all components must be valid
        return _.isEmpty(_.difference(component.types, validTypes)); // there shouldn't be any types that are not in the valid
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally,  I think it reads easier if you replace the `_.isEmpty()` logic with:  `_.every(component.types, type => _.includes(validTypes, type))`

Comment: Unless told otherwise, readability trumps performance, imo.   (Though I don't see why that would be any less performant than `_.difference`)

Comment: Trump is an interesting choice of words this week

Comment: Thank you guys, somehow I had missed _.every(). I went for @Retsam suggestion by the way.